# simplecov custom filter group to report ignored code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, simplecov

I am trying to create a report in simplecov to report on rogue actions within my application.  Basically I want a tab that reports any and only files that use the `:nocov:` parameter to prevent simplecov from reporting it.  Now, I know these may not be all bad, so I only want to filter them to a tab and not affect the overall score.

Currently I have the custom tab setup, but the filter does not filter the files correctly.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: custom tab]

Sample simple cov ignored method:

```
# :nocov:
def my_debug_method
  do_something
end
# :nocov:
```

Here is my current `.simplecov` setup:

```
class IgnoredCodeFilter < SimpleCov::Filter
  def matches?(src_file)
    src_file.grep(/:nocov:/).size > 0
  end
end
SimpleCov.start do
  add_group "Ignored Code" do |src_file|
    IgnoredCodeFilter.new(src_file)
  end
end
```

Current error message:

```
Formatter SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `grep' for #<SimpleCov::SourceFile:0x007f920e166fa0> (.simplecov:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I ultimately solved this issue in case others are looking for it.

Just add this to your `.simplecov` configuration file:

```
SimpleCov.start do
  add_group "Ignored Code" do |src_file|
    open(src_file.filename).grep(/:nocov:/).any?
  end
end
```